# Register Form PHP not inserting values into DB, just reloading the page

Tags: php, mysql

I really can not find what am I doing wrong in my registration form, unfortunately the page is just reloading instead of inserting values from form to my DB table.

Register.php

```
<?php 
require_once("./Connection.php");

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        $firstName = $_POST['firstName'];
        $lastName = $_POST['lastName'];
        $email  = $_POST['email'];
        $phone  = $_POST['phone'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];
        
        $options = array("cost"=>5);
        $hashPassword = password_hash($password,PASSWORD_BCRYPT,$options);
        
        $sql = "insert into agents (firstName, lastName, email, phone, password) value ('".$firstName."', '".$lastName."', '".$email."','".$phone."','".$hashPassword."')";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        if($result)
        {
            echo "Registration successfully";
        }
    }
?>
```

Connection.php

```
<?php 
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","KBHestate");
 
if(!$conn){
    die("Connection error: " . mysqli_connect_error()); 
}
```

Register Form

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="firstName" value="" placeholder="First Name">
    <input type="text" name="lastName" value="" placeholder="Surname">
    <input type="text" name="email" value="" placeholder="Email">
    <input type="text" name="phone" value="" placeholder="Phone">
    <input type="password" name="password" value="" placeholder="Password">
    <button type="submit" name="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please make sure the following line has no problem when it is interpreted by the PHP:

```
$options = array("cost"=>5);
$hashPassword = password_hash($password,PASSWORD_BCRYPT,$options);
```

On the other hand, please make sure that the password field is wide enough to store the $hasPassword data

Comment: Oh damn, I made a typo mistake in password length - thank you for reminding me to check on it.

Comment: Good to note that you have fixed the problem , please mark it answered so that we can close this question. (Have fun in coding)

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine, it should work. I am hoping you are having Register form in the same file Register.php

But as you mentioned it's just reload the page that means there must be a exception/error from mysql query that is not handled in your code.
You have not shared your table structure. So, I am answering you based on the common mistake.

Like one of your table column width is varchar(10) and you are trying to pass data of length 20 char.

So, i suggest you to add below code in your Register.php as the else condition for if($result). So, it will display the error if any.

```
else {
            echo("Error description: " . $conn->error);
     }
```

Now your Register.php code will be look like below:

```
<?php 
require_once("./Connection.php");

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        $firstName = $_POST['firstName'];
        $lastName = $_POST['lastName'];
        $email  = $_POST['email'];
        $phone  = $_POST['phone'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];
        
        $options = array("cost"=>5);
        $hashPassword = password_hash($password,PASSWORD_BCRYPT,$options);
        
        $sql = "insert into agents (firstName, lastName, email, phone, password) value ('".$firstName."', '".$lastName."', '".$email."','".$phone."','".$hashPassword."')";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        if($result)
        {
            echo "Registration successfully";
        }else {
            echo("Error description: " . $conn->error);
        }
    }
?>
```